# How to access 'foreign' fields in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two angularjs models and I would like to use `firstkey` of `firstcollection` as index value in the `anothercollention`. Basically I want to iterate over anothercollention.firstkey using the key from the previous ng-repeat. Here is some code which I hope makes sense of what I'm trying to do. I've checked all the angularjs docs but none seems to provide an example for this scenario. All of them assume that you have the data in the same ng-repeat model.

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="(firstkey, value) in firstcollection"></li>
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="(subkey, subvalue) in anothercollention.firstkey"></li>
<ul>
</ul>

Example
  first collection  {"fruits": "are the best", "veggies": "are the worst"} 
  another collection {"fruits": [1, 2, 3 ], "veggies":[2,4,5]},
   HTML page should look like this:
   fruits are the best
   1, 2, 3
   veggies are the worst
   2,4,5
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  If you are iterating over a collection that is a node of the previous collection, then you can do it with nested DIVs (UL might not work, depending on how you want it to show up).  A little clearer explanation might help.

Comment: could you show the structure of `anothercollention` and correct closing tags(to understand if your ng-repeats is nested or not).

Comment: @Beartums I've posted some dummy data. I just want to group the iterate over "anothercollection" using a key from the first collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess I got it. All you need to do is:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="(firstkey, value) in firstcollection"></li>
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="(subkey, subvalue) in anothercollention[firstkey]"></li>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat There is a few ways to access field of object in javascript, you can read more in docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors